# usercontrol push out from Window when animation running in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-animation

I used TranslateTransfrom animation for show usercontrols , but usercontrol pushed out from window when animate. screenshots :

[image]

blue rectangle shows my problem , i changed window content for show usercontrols and i tried change Grid (that into window) Content but result not changed. any idea?

**main question :**

how to limit animation to a grid?

Excuse me for poor English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set margin value

margin="5 5 0 0"

Comment: i recently tested this but not make any difference!

Comment: tnx , please download from this link : [project.rar](http://stickerbox.operand.ir/Project.rar)

Comment: I tried this one its working fine in my system.i set margin value margin="5 5 0 0"

Comment: Where exactly should I change?

Comment: 1.First adjust Mainwindow height and width and decrease the grid height and width value  try this one (or) 2.set margin value in grid control